# Android - File Won't Move or Copy to Internal App Storage

Tags: java, android, file, copy, move

I have an app that uses DownloadManager to download some files to the basic internal music directory, found by using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)`. I want to move the music files to my app's internal storage to make it less likely for a user to accidentally delete those files. I am getting the path to the app's internal storage directory with `getFilesDir()`. However, with almost everything I try, they don't appear there. Here is what I've done:

**AndroidManifest.xml**: I've set the necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**renameTo()**: I've tried using the `renameTo()` function but it always returns false:

```
        if(src.renameTo(dst)){
            Log.d("File Move", "File successfully moved");
        } else{
            Log.e("File move", "File was not successfully moved");
        }
```

**InputStream and OutputStream**:

```
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dst);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len = is.read(buff)) > 0){
                os.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
```

And this is the code for the full directories:

```
String sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE)) + ".mp3";
String destinationPath = getFilesDir() + "/" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE)) + ".mp3";
```

I get no errors for FileIO Exceptions or anything like that. The files just don't appear in the specified target directory. Any help or insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is src? What is dst?

Comment: How do you check if the files appear?

Answer (score 0):

*Solution:*

Create a shareable_paths.xml at res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="sdcard1"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Add the following to your Manifest file:

```
<application>
     ...
      <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/shareable_paths"/>
        </provider>
      ...
      ...
</application>
```

*Reason:*

File provider must be set to perform storage actions

Comment: I just tried this. The files still don't appear in the specified path in the emulator. I tried on my actual phone but I don't think I have access to that directory because my phone isn't rooted

Comment: Root should not be an issue, have you taken permissions from user using Request Permission? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: `File provider must be set to perform storage actions`. Not at all. Not within the same app.